# Printing out line from CSV file that contains user input -

Tags: java, csv, io

I have a program that allows the user to input observations into a CSV file and save them. 
I want to be able to read the file and only print out observations that the user searches for. (ex. user types in "planet" and all lines containing planet are printed out. My current code prints out the whole file, and not just the specified lines. I'm having trouble setting up a logical statement to do this.

Here's my code:

```
void findbird() throws IOException{


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the type of bird you wish to search for");
    String bird;
    bird = input.next();
    System.out.println("All observations of " + bird + "s:");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("birdobservations.txt"));
    String dataRow = br.readLine();
    boolean contains = bird.toLowerCase().contains(dataRow.toLowerCase());

    while (dataRow != null){
        String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
        for (String item:dataArray) { 
            if(contains = true){
                System.out.print(item + "\t"); 
            }else{
                System.out.println("No observations of " + bird + " found!");
            }

        }

        System.out.println(); 
        dataRow = br.readLine(); 
    }

    br.close();
    System.out.println();

    menu();
}
```

My output currently looks like this:

> Please enter the type of bird you wish to search for
>
> Crow
>
> All observations of Crows:     Crow   X   Bergen  May2015
>
> Woodpecker    M   Oslo    July2012
>
> Hummingbird   M   Kaupanger   December2015

Whereas I only want to print out:

> Crow  X   Bergen  May2015

Comment: shouldn't `if(contains = true)` be `if(contains == true)`

Comment: Oops, yes. I changed that but still the same output.

Comment: Or simply `if(contains)`.

Comment: Tried that, still prints out the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.... the two most glaring are:

1. `boolean contains = bird.toLowerCase().contains(dataRow.toLowerCase());` should surely be the other way around (dataRow...contains(...bird...))
2. You never reset the boolean variable `contains` so that it will print everything after it first is set to true... there has to be a `contains = false` somewhere

In general, you should probably have a loop that looks like:

```
String dataRow = null;
while ( (dataRow = scanner.readLine() ) != null) {
   ....
}
```

That way you do not need to do the silly readLine outside the loop as well, which makes your code cumbersome.

Once you have fixed up these code issues then come back again with an edited question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem code

```
        String dataRow = br.readLine();
        boolean contains = bird.toLowerCase().contains(dataRow.toLowerCase());

    while (dataRow != null){
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
        for (String item:dataArray) { 
            if(contains = true){
                System.out.print(item + "\t"); 
            }else{
                System.out.println("No observations of " + bird + " found!");
            }
 }
```

Change it to

```
while((dataRow = br.readline())!= null)
{
//And now you get value of contain and then check if contain == true and add other piece of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your `contains` check is the wrong way around. The format is `string.contains(substring)`.
- `contains` should be moved inside the loop, otherwise you just set it once in the beginning, instead of for each row.
- `contains = true` should be `contains == true` or simply `contains`. `contains = true` is assignment and will always return `true`, regardless of the value `contains` had.
- Move the `contains` check outside the for-loop, otherwise it will print a message for each column in the row, not just once per row.
- `System.out.println();` will cause blank lines to be printed, if this is unwanted (it probably is), it should be removed.

Code:

```
while (dataRow != null){
    boolean contains = dataRow.toLowerCase().contains(bird.toLowerCase());
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
    if(contains){
        for (String item:dataArray) { 
            System.out.print(item + "\t"); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No observations of " + bird + " found!");
    }

    dataRow = br.readLine(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely what I was looking for! I'm getting lots of blank lines in my output though, which correspond to the lines in the file that don't match. Is there any way to trim this?

Answer (score 0):

You have your logic backwards. Do:

```
 boolean contains = dataRow.toLowerCase().contains(bird.toLowerCase());
```

Also, the fact that you have:

```
            if(contains = true){
                System.out.print(item + "\t"); 
            }else{
                System.out.println("No observations of " + bird + " found!");
            }
```

means that `contains` will always be true, because you are assigning `true` to contains. You need to do:

```
        if(contains == true){
            System.out.print(item + "\t"); 
        }else{
            System.out.println("No observations of " + bird + " found!");
        }
```

Comment: the line   if (contains = true) is also in error (should be == (or no = true), consider adding it to your answer.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that.